# Iterate mediator in message processor

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a question regarding to apply Iterate mediator in sequence of Message Processor. Let's me show you more detail.
First, i have a message which has been stored in Message store:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soapenv:Body>
         <jsonObject>
            <status>success</status>
            <totalCount>2</totalCount>
            <next></next>
            <profiles>
               <href>1391671019717</href>
               ...
            </profiles>
            <profiles>
              ......
            </profiles>
         </jsonObject>
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then, i created one Message Processor to use that message store above

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ProfileProcessingSEQ">
    <iterate id="each_profile" preservePayload="true" attachPath="//jsonObject" expression="//jsonObject/profiles">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <log>
                    <property name="message" expression="//jsonObject/profiles/profiles"/>
                </log>
                <send/>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
</sequence>
```

After Message Processor invoked, i saw the error log like this:

> java.util.EmptyStackException at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
>   at
>   org.apache.synapse.continuation.ContinuationStackManager.addReliantContinuationState(ContinuationStackManager.java:103)
>   at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.splitter.IterateMediator.mediate(IterateMediator.java:144
>   at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
>   at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
>   at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)

Does anyone has the same that problem? Please give me  some opinions

Thanks,

Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve that issue, i have to change the way to process, to split and prepare the message before storing into message store and it work successfully.
Does any one have another idea?

Regards,
Leon